# stuck on splash screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

when is push my app on google play store then download from play store then that app is stuck on splash screen but my app is run perfectly other device but only stuck on one pluce devices flutter project
Note - my app is release mode run perfectly an debug mode run perfectly

Comment: Did you test in release mode?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have any impact on the internet in the beginning?

If yes, check your AndroidManifest.xml file has INTERNET permission or not.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```